# MultiDatespicker : exclude weekends from pickableRange and adjustRangeToDisabled

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-multidatespicker

I am working with jquery **[multidatespicker](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/#pickableRange-demo)** where I have to define a range of dates to be allowed after the first date has been picked.

I need to **exclude** the **weekends** from all the future dates. However, pickableRange doesn't skip the weekends that are disabled with **beforeShowDay**.

I also tried adding **addDisabledDates** but it is not feasible to add all the weekend dates in an array.

This is the code that I have been trying.

```
$('#id').multiDatesPicker({
    pickableRange: 15,
    adjustRangeToDisabled: true,
    beforeShowDay:  $.datepicker.noWeekends,
    addDisabledDates : ['array containing all weekends and holidays'] // not feasible option
})
```

Kindly help me out here..

Comment: beforeShowDay didnt work?

Comment: It disables the weekends but does not add the dates to **disabledDates** of the instance.. Hence doesn't skip the dates.

Answer (score 7):

```
$('#id').multiDatesPicker({
  beforeShowDay: disableSpecificWeekDays,
  // For disabling all "Sundays and saturday"
  dateFormat: "d/m/yy",
  maxDate: "+3m",
  minDate: "-1m",
  multidate: true,
});

function disableSpecificWeekDays(date) {
  var theday = date.getDate() + '/' +
      (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' +date.getFullYear();
  var day = date.getDay();
    return [day != 0 && day != 6];
}
```

Here we can assign a method for disabling a weekend.
please try this.

Comment: This is not the answear to the question, should be downvoted. The question clearly states that it doesn't work with autoselected ranges.

Comment: @KronosL Thank you for your attention. I have added a possible solution only. I have tried in my way. If you have a better solution kindly please upload it. I too wanna get the best way to do that.